# regex to detect file structure in java

Tags: java, regex

I want to detect the file structure in a string.
e.g
if I have a string as /name/test/testme/2 I should be able to store it in a arraylist as different elements like {[name],[test],[testme],[2]}

Comment: show your effort. don't simply request for code. at least show what have you tried so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String[] elements = "/name/test/testme/2".split("/");
```

More info can be found in the [`String.split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) Javadoc

Comment: Yes thats a good answer. Can't figure out why I didn't get that in my mind.
But actually I wanted it to achieve through Pattern and Matcher classes, using the regex.

Comment: sounds like [XyProblem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) :p

Comment: @HVT7: Then, have a look at `split()`'s source code. `split()` is just convenience for the corresponding, more verbose `Pattern` and `Matcher` calls

Answer (score 0):

As Lukas pointed out, (please give him some upvoting) you should use the split method.

```
String[] elements = "/name/test/testme/2".split("/");
```

The regular expressions are not used to split strings in sections. Regular expressions are used for matching the target string with a specific generic format. In this case a boolean value indicating if the strings match is returned.

Hope I helped!

Comment: @HVT7 Thank you. It is important for people navigating to a question to be able to recognize a constructive answer...

Comment: Agreed...!!
Will surely remember it from now...!!